# C++ global scope class

Tags: c++, class, scope, namespaces, global

I'm learning c++ and I make a program to show input numbers using classes.
I used constructors to initialize the `x` and `y`. The program works fine but I wanted to use the global scope to show the variables instead of a function.
The commented lines is what I wanted it to do but it gives me an error, I tried instead using `dublu::x` and `dublu::y` but it says that constants need to be `static const`... this works but it's not a solution for me. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class dublu{
public:
    int x,y;
    dublu(){cin>>x>>y;};
    dublu(int,int);
void show(void);
};

dublu::dublu(int x, int y){
dublu::x = x;
dublu::y = y;
}

void dublu::show(void){
cout << x<<","<< y<<endl;
}

namespace second{
    double x = 3.1416;
    double y = 2.7183;
}
using namespace second;

int main () {
    dublu test,test2(6,8);
    test.show();
    test2.show();
    /*cout << test::x << '\n';
    cout << test::y << '\n';*/
    cout << x << '\n';
    cout << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member variables are bounded to each instance. So you need to use

```
cout << test.x << '\n';
```

instead, and similarly for `test.y`. Right now you are using `test::x`, which works only if the member variable is *static*, i.e. is shared among all instances of your class.